# Python: output of scapy cannot be stored in a text file?

Tags: python, windows, scapy

When runnning scapy from command prompt (windows XP), the output cannot be stored. When the following command is executed in command prompt:

```
scapy >C:\dir.txt
```

The following error shows up:

```
C:\automation\atg\GeneralFiles_AC\ScapyExe>scapy >C:\dir.txt INFO:
Can't import python gnuplot wrapper . Won't be able to plot. INFO:
Can't import PyX. Won't be able to use psdump() or pdfdump(). INFO: No
IPv6 support in kernel WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\crypto\cert.py:6:
DeprecationWarning?: the sh a module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead
import os, sys, math, socket, struct, sha, hmac, string, time 
C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\crypto\cert.py:7: DeprecationWarning?: The popen2 module is deprecated. Use the subprocess module. 
import random, popen2, tempfile 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Python26\Scripts\\scapy", line 25, in <module> 
interact() 
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\main.py", line 293, in interact 
readline.read_history_file(conf.histfile) 
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 183, in read_history_file 
self._history.read_history_file(filename) 
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\lineeditor\history.py", line 70, in read_history_file 
self.add_history(lineobj.ReadLineTextBuffer?(ensure_unicode(line.rstrip()))) 
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\unicode_helper.py", line 20, in ensure_unicode 
return text.decode(pyreadline_codepage, "replace") 
TypeError?: decode() argument 1 must be string, not None 

C:\automation\atg\GeneralFiles_AC\ScapyExe>
```

system specifications:
OS: windows XP
scapy version: 2.1.1-dev (using scapy-7a97e2f3db67.zip)
Python: 2.6 (PythonWin?)

Comment: Please edit your question.  The formatting guidelines are on the right side of the page.  If you indent code (and logs of sessions), it is much more readable.

Comment: Are you sure that you have all the necessary Python submodule dependencies installed correctly? Looks like it can't find some of them.

Comment: @S.Lott - Sorry, this is my 1st time.
@dublev - I have installed all the necessary dependencies. I followed http://dirk-loss.de/scapy-doc/_sources/installation.txt link to download scapy and its dependencies (related to python 2.6).

Comment: Don't apologize.  Fix your formatting, please.

Comment: The list of "optional software for special features" should do it.  If you continue to have errors after installing the necessary dependencies, could you update your error messages in this post?

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#windows) on installing optional packages for Windows here.

Comment: can you be little more specific as to which optional package am I missing just to store the output of scapy in a text file?

thanks
Amit

Comment: Yes, -1. Please clarify. I'm also having this issue. I'm not sure this has anything to do with it because I have installed all the packages and still have the same preblem. Also there's this scapy issue: http://trac.secdev.org/scapy/ticket/357